# IS it safe to delete wow64 dll's when autoruns says so?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, autorun

I have Windows 8 64-bit.

I run **Autoruns** (latest version) and it states 3 DLLs which are not found:

[image]

**Question**

Is it safe to delete those entries with Autoruns?

Comment: Why do you want to delete required system files?  wow64.dll allows you to run 32-bit software.

Comment: @Ramhound I dont want. autoruns want. it says they are not there

Comment: You asked if its safe to delete those files, its not safe, the registry key might be pointing to the wrong location but thats another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a windows Black Magic (TM): http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/wow64dll-wow64cpudll-wow64windll-files-not-found/837ba758-ad0a-4bc3-b227-62046f7e198d?msgId=762f85e0-f11f-481b-a0e8-b92971acf422

> Don't be concerned if autoruns reports these files as not found.   Just ignore it.  These three files are critical to (and invisible to) 32-bit processes running on a 64-bit processor.
>
> For a little fun you can see this by launching both the native and x86 versions of Windows PowerShell, type the following in both.   Somewhat surprisingly you'll get different results:
>
> ```
> cd $env:windir\system32
> dir wow*
> ```

Comment: holly shi* , in powershell i do see those files. while in pure cmd - i don't. why is that ?

Comment: Because they are not there. The systems transparently 'shows' this files in desired location depending whether the app is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

It is not safe to delete those dll files. Those listed files supports 32 bit applications running in 64 bit machine.Instead of deleting dll files try to register dll by typing
`regsvr32 /s wow64win.dll` in command propmt with administrator privillege

Comment: the files are not in file system !

Comment: Run a file system scan by typing `SFC /SCANNOW` in command propmt. also do a check for those dll in `system32` folder by going to system 32 folder from a command line and then type `dir wow*`