# cmd closes immediately after I (say) accidentally deleted sysWow64 folder

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, system-restore

I had viruses on my system. So I deleted them by AV. One persisted though. The AV asked to Resolve it so I just went into `Windows/SysWow64` It had a folder and inside folder an exe. Both had some gibberish names like zX.. so I changed the rights and deleted it. Problem solved.

But now when my `cmd` is not persisting. Though BAT files were launched, I found out that it was for `32-bit` system.

So how can I restore it so that my command prompt can be launched properly?

Here is a related answer [link](https://superuser.com/q/652780/654156), I 've already read.

Comment: Easy and sure way (though not fastest): reinstall Windows in repair mode.

Comment: In face I was looking for a installer of some kind?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8

Comment: Interestingly, when I restart computer. The windows repaired itself. Before I insert media. Thanks @DrMoishePippik